# GNU makefiles remaking existing targets

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a simple makefile on my machine:

```makefile
# Compiler: g++ for C++ source files
CC = g++

# Compiler flags:
CFLAGS = -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O0 -c

foo.o: foo.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $?

bar.o: bar.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $?

foobar: foo.o bar.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $?
```

When I run `make` it remakes each target, even if it already exists. I want the makefile to ignore existing targets. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior so there's something about your makefile or your environment you are not telling us.  What is the actual `make` command you invoke, and what output do you see (edit your question and add this with proper formatting)?

Comment: Just to note, it's wrong to use `$?` here.  Regardless of which files have been updated, or not, you _always_ want to compile and link the same files.  You should use `$<` in your compile rule, and `$^` in your link rule.  But, this won't cause the targets to rebuild every time.

Comment: I'm using a stripped down version of debian 10. Would that affect this?

I'm using the recommended debian for beaglebones "AM3358 Debian 10.3 2020-04-06 4GB SD IoT"... it does not a lot of capability only command-line.

Comment: You don't need a display (if by "a display" you mean a graphical desktop) to run make: it's a command-line tool.

Comment: My question was more if a different version of linux could affect GNU make functionality.

Comment: I also get a "clock skew detected" message but the makefile still runs.

Comment: Aha!!  If you get a clock skew detected that is most likely the reason everything is rebuilding.  Make works by comparing timestamps.  If your source files have a timestamp which is "in the future", then when the compiler runs and writes out the object files they will still be older than the source files, and the next time you run make it will build them again.  You need to ensure that all your systems are synced to the same clock, or else ensure that the timestamps of your files are relative to the system you're running make on.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this fixed my problem:

```
# Compiler: g++ for C++ source files
CC = g++

# Compiler flags:
CFLAGS = -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O0 -c

all: foo.o bar.o foobar

foo.o: foo.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $<

bar.o: bar.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $<

foobar: foo.o bar.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

and also

```
touch makefile
```